# Android get width of ListView in Adapter's GetView Method

Tags: android, listview, adapter

How can I get the Width of a `ListView` in `Adapter's` `GetView` method ?

ParentLayout of the `View` inflated is a `RelativeLayout` with width as `match_parent`

Following is what I have tried

```
Display display = ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
maxWidth = size.x;        
int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth , View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
convertView.findViewById(R.id.TagMasterLayout).measure(specWidth , specWidth);
int totalWidth = convertView.findViewById(R.id.TagMasterLayout).getMeasuredWidth();
```

In this example, I always get the Width of the screen of the device. As I have set the `MeasureSpec` to accept a maximum value of Width of the device's screen.

Instead if I do,

```
int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

And rest all portion as same, I get a huge value greater than 1000 (which is greater than device screen width, because variable `maxWidth` had a value of only 720).

So How can I exactly measure the width of a `ListView` with Width as `fill_parent` in `getView` method of Adapter class ?

Comment: Can you also mention why do you need the width?

Comment: I want to add tags (TextViews of dynamic length) in a horizontal LinearLayout within the inflated view. I want to detect when the Layout is filled. So would like to have the width of the full layout initially

Comment: I ask this because you should ideally be able to do this without getting the size programmatically.So maybe if you explained a bit more in the question,we could try solving it more easily and robustly using xmls.

Comment: @Droidekas My requirement is that, I want to populate a horizontal linearlayout with N number of textviews having dynamic texts such that it exactly fits the width of the LinearLayout. So can that be handled with Xmls ?

Comment: Thinking logically, I feel it might be impossible to acheive what I have asked for. Because, we set an adapter TO a view. So I don't see any chance of getting the Width of the view to which adapter is going to be set from the adapter. Or is there anything that I have overlooked that makes it possible to measure ?

Comment: Hmm,it should be possible.Can you add your item layout and the logic of your tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get width of parent view. It is a view to which your view will be attached to.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    ...

    parent.getWidth();

    ...
    return v;
}
```

`parent.getWidth()` will return you the width of `ListView`.

Comment: make sure you are calling getWidth after the view is drawn, otherwise it will return 0